# How to build jar for a project which depends on other project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, unity-game-engine

I am using C#(Unity) to call java function in jar. My class is like:

```
Class A{
  auth(){
  }
  share(){
    StatusesAPI mStatusesAPI; 
    mStatusesAPI.upload("hey", bitmap, null, null, mListener);
      ........

  }
```

}

. auth() can be call in c# and works correctly if I comment everything related to StatusesAPI, such like,

```
//private StatusesAPI mStatusesAPI; 

//mStatusesAPI.upload("hey", bitmap, null, null, mListener);
```

Now, because I need this class(StatusesAPI ) to do something, I have to uncomment it and then import it. This Class is in project B and it depends on other classes in project B. So I add project B in Eclipse JAVA BUILD PATH. NO compile error. I enter

```
jar -cvf plugin.jar *
```

in cmd under folder myproject/bin/class

and I move the plugin.jar to unity /bin folder.
But when c# call auth(), error happens.

I doubt StatusesAPI code is not include into my plugin.jar, that makes class A all function don't work. I have tested calling my other class functions in plugin.jar, they works.

Any one know how to deal with this? How to make both auth() and share() works.

Comment: You have to package the other project into your jar. The eclipse export wizards have options for this.

Comment: @Dawnkeeper I have try export->choose jar file->tick my project and project B, tick export generated classes file and resources, tick export java source file and resource,tick compress the content of jar file. press finish. I got a jar but it still doesn't works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you try import the jar file by

1. right click on your project main folder.
2. select Build Path then configure build path.
3. Under libraries choose the required jar file usi(plugin.jar) by Add External Jar's(go to the destination folder).
4. Click ok and once restart the IDE.
5. Hope this helps you

Comment: I dont know what your mean of step 3. plugin.jar is my project's output jar why I should include it. Do you mean include project B's jar

Comment: @Deco sorry its not dependencies it is libraries see my edit now (Changed step 3)